# Is the function 1/x differentiable?

Tags: calculus

This question is about the usage of the word "differentiable". You can't talk about the function not being differentiable in $x =0$ simply because it is not defined there. Isn't it then correct to say, that the function is differentiable? Wouldn't it be the same for the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac1x$ is not defined when $x=0$.  So what is its domain?

Comment: "because it is not defined there. Isn't it then correct to say, that the function is differentiable? "  Mmmm.  It's debatable.  Maybe semantical.  Every one agrees 1) it is differentiable on all points it is defined, ii) that is not defined and/or differentiable at x=0.  what is debatable is whether "it is not differentiable on all R" is a meaningful statement.  As dom(f) is not R it's arguable such a comment is meaningless and/or irrelevant.  I'm more or less in that camp.  On the other hand applicationwise R is so relevent that noting a function fails at x=0 is not... impertainent.

Comment: @fleablood, look at the definition of differentiability at $a$: That the limit  $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ must exit. If $f(x)$ is not defined in $a$, then you can't calculate $f(a)$, hence it makes no sense to talk about differentiability at $a$.

Comment: Oh, I agree and I made that exact argument.  But if f the lim doesn't exist then it is *not* true that f is differentiable at x=a.  And if it is not true that fi is differentiable at x=a, then f is *not* differentiable at x=a.  Likewise f(x) is not differentiable at x = "pink-honk-honk" either.  Most mathematians would say "1/x is differentiable" because to most mathematicians "differentiable" = "differentiable for all dom(f)".  But I think many scientists and practical mathematicians may take "differentiable" = "differentiable for all Reals".  They are wrong. But...

Comment: ... it is misleading to say "1/x is differentiable so STFU".  It is relevent to point out.  "1/x is undefined as x = 0 so x is not in dom(1/x), so it isn't relevant to talk of whether is differentiable there".

Comment: If you dont define the domain and codomain of a function then its not defined. From this point of view $f(x)=1/x$ is not a function, so it dont care to talk about it differentiability.

Answer (score 3):

Excert from wikipedia (use a better source if you have one)

> A differentiable function of one real variable is a function whose derivative exists at each point in its domain.

Let $f = (x\mapsto \frac{1}{x})$. For any $x \in \mathrm{dom} (f) = \mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$, $f$ is differentiable at $x$.  Does that make $f$ differentiable ?

For any $x \in \mathrm{dom}(g)$, is $g$ differentiable at $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, it will? Just as I said?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  You restrict your analysis to the domain of $f$; it's in the definition.

Comment: I just got confused, because some textbooks and internetsides talk about $\frac{1}{x}$ not being differentiable in $x=0$, which is indeed incorrect, since it makes no sense to talk about differentiability.

Comment: Those text book are right as you point out, but over all $f$ is differentiable "on every point of its domain".  The quoted part being implied when saying a *function* is differentiable.

Comment: I got that part. I think, that you still misunderstand me. I mean, that the sentence "$\frac{1}{x}$ is non-differentiable at $x=0$" is wrong.

Comment: @HamidMohammad As a side note, for the same reason, $f$ is continuous. It's a common mistake to think it's not.

Comment: Depends on how you understand "non-differentiable".  I take it to means "has not the property of being differentiable at $0$, which having not $0$ in the domain implies.  But your way is fine too.

Comment: Thanks. That was the question from the every start. The other things were trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If a function 
$f$
is not defined at a value
$a$,
then it is
not differentiable at
$a$
because the derivative
is *defined* by
$\lim_{x \to a}
\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$
and the fraction
$
\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$
is not defined.

If $f$ is defined
in a neighborhood or $a$,
you *can*
write
$\lim_{y \to a} f'(y)
=\lim_{y \to a}\lim_{x \to y}
\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
$.
Whether this double limit exists
depends on  how
$f$ acts close to $a$.
If $f$ has a removable discontinuity,
such as
$f(x) = x$ for $x \ne 0$
and $f(0) = 1$,
then the limit exists.
If $f$ has an essential
discontinuity,
such as
$f(x) = \frac1{x}$,
the limit of the derivative
does not exist.